# How to convert from c# ShortDatePattern to moment.js equivalent

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, momentjs, pikaday

I have a multilingual site. I have a model with a DateTime? field. I am using pikaday to allow the picking of dates.

I had set up the date to be the format of

```
'DD/MM/YYYY'
```

When using the Swedish local the short date it is excecting is yyyy-MM-dd. So the model is not binding the DateTime? field.

I thought when setting the format for pikaday I could use

```
@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

However I can't go from a C# ShortDatePattern to a moment.js pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work in my test cases

```
@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.Replace("yyyy", "YYYY").Replace('d','D')
```